# Ubuntu PPTP VPN to Microsoft Server Command Line ONLY

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, command-line-interface, pptp

I try to setup a VPN Connection from a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to Microsoft VPN Server (Ubuntu is the Client in this Case),
but I only get this error message:

```
.. connection failed! Check the log messages below for information why.
Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Operation not permitted 
FATAL: Module ppp_generic not found./usr/sbin/pppd: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support
```

Details you may need:

```
modprobe -v ppp > FATAL: Module ppp not found.
uname -r -> 2.6.32-042stab076.8
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `apt-cache search ppp`

Answer (score 1):

You're on a VPS on someone else's OpenVZ VPS hosting. Therefore you have no access to kernel modules and can only use the modules that the provider chooses to allow you.

To resolve the issue, contact the hosting provider. If the hosting provider is unable or unwilling to fix it, take your business somewhere else (and preferably somewhere not using OpenVZ).

Comment: It doesn't say it's someone elses VZ container.. It might be his..

Comment: @TomO'Connor If he was the provider, he would have mentioned it. They always do, without fail. At least for OpenVZ...

Comment: OpenVZ sucks anyway.

Comment: the output of apt-cache search ppp ->
http://pastebin.com/pQvhYDkL

Comment: Your package list is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: we updated the server to the newest version, now we have a different error message with the same result:

Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Operation not permitted
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:505 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file: could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab076.8/modules.builtin.bin'
FATAL: Module ppp_generic not found.
/usr/sbin/pppd: Sorry - this system lacks PPP kernel support

Comment: the provider uses Virtuozzo, so i guess the openVZ argument from Michael is correct ? is there any way for us to realie the vpn connection from there ?

Comment: Virtuozzo and OpenVZ are effectively the same thing, and work the same for this purpose.

Comment: so if the provider doesnt support vpn we can't do anything ?
can we "proof" it somehow that virtuozzo is the problem, otherwise the provider will say that our problem...

Comment: Any provider operating Virtuozzo or OpenVZ is well aware of this issue. If you actually have a problem with them, then they are not worth spending money on.

Comment: first of all thx michael for your quick response.
could you please be a bit more specific what exactly the problem is ( virtuozzo <-> vpn/ppp ) so i can discuss that with the hotline.

Comment: What more do you want? If you already had a conversation with them, then you need to go find another provider now. If you didn't, then you need to go do that now.

Comment: the biggest german vps provider is unable to solve this, they told us that they can't provide ppp or any vpn service because of openVZ/Virtuozzo.

Comment: I already answered that. Now you get to go find a VPS provider who are not a lot of incompetent morons..